# JS ES6: Import { functionName } is undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm exporting a list of functions from `./list`:

```
export default {
  f1: a,
  f2: b,
  f3: c
}
```

Where a,b,c are separate functions, and trying to import one of the functions into another file:

```
import { f1 } from './list';
```

But `f1()` is `undefined` in the new file. If I import as:

```
import list from './list';
```

And call `list.f1()` it IS defined.

How can I import `{ f1 }` as defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this

```
export {
  a as f1,
  b as f2,
  c as f3
}
```

To have a clear understanding you can have a look at [this export doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Comment: I'm guessing because that would be invalid

Answer (score 0):

There may not be any need of the brace while importing it

```
import test from "./alphaTest";
test.f1();


export default{
  f1: function a(){
    alert('a')
  },
  f2: function b(){
    alert('b')
  },
  f3: function c(){
    alert('c')
  }
}
```

Check this [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-4awvtp?file=alphaTest.js)